# Controlling a mobile phone to send a request

Tags: c#, c++, eclipse, mobile

I want to control almost any mobile phone or at least Nokia to send a Request of course using my computer.

you see I have a friend of mine who found a way to send a command to the mobile phone but the phone understood it as a CALL not a Request.

you see in my counrty to know how much unit you have in your mobile Acount you have to write on your mobile *100# then hit the green button "Call button" when you do that your mobile shows "sending request..." or something like it.

okay I want to send this request to the mobile.
and even retreiving the coming message of course after the request.

I program in C#, C++, and I'm learning Java using Eclipse.

please help me.

Comment: maybe I need to send USSD commands using computer If you can help poeple please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a program for the phone, and interact with the computer via Bluetooth or the Internet.

Comment: How can i do that please help with links or say more please